# How do you incorporate forked projects w/ yarn?

Tags: javascript, git-submodules, yarnpkg

I'm building a proprietary piece of software that utilizes this piece of software:

https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid

I need to fork this project to make custom modifications. It's fine that the project stays public, but my project is in a private repo. I'm using yarn instead of npm. My goal is to quickly make changes to `react-data-grid`, push them to github, and then pull those changes into my project so when I import `react-data-grid` and refresh, the new grid shows up.

There appears to be two ways to do this:

1. Use git submodules
2. Use `yarn add` but point it at my custom version of `react-data-grid`

I was wondering if anyone could provide the pros/cons of each approach, and if you suggest yarn , please explain the step-by-step process to do this.